# QueryDSL - select rows with date from timestamp column

Tags: querydsl

Using QueryDSL - is there a way to select rows by date from a timestamp other than using .between? Something like this query:

> where convert(date, mytimestamp) = '2013-02-28'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use between or a custom expression if you use Querydsl SQL

Something like this

```
DateExpression<Date> converted = DateTemplate.create(Date.class, "convert(date, {0})", mytimestamp);
```

Comment: Should it be "DateExpression<Date> converted = ..."? At least I got it working that way, and using "converted" in my BooleanBuilder. Thanks :)

Comment: Timo Westkämper, create() mathod is not available in com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.DateTemplate<T>. How to overcome this?

Comment: @spr U can use `Expressions.dateTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

Time portion can be truncated using `Expressions::dateTimeOperation`. See below example:

```
import com.querydsl.core.BooleanBuilder;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Ops;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.*;

...

public Iterable<Entity> getList(Date createdOn) {

    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    BooleanExpression compareDatePart = Expressions.dateTimeOperation(
                Date.class, Ops.DateTimeOps.DATE,
                QEntity.entity.timestamp).eq(createdOn);
    Predicate predicate = builder.and(compareDatePart).getValue();
 
    return entityRepository.findAll(predicate);
}

...
```